# How to write update query for each row in temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

After some calculation, I am compiling a list of records that need to be updated:

```
ID    Name    Value
-------------------
1     A       foo
2     B       bar
9     C       baz
```

I want to update only these records in a major table:

```
update table set name = A, value = foo where ID = 1
update table set name = B, value = bar where ID = 2
update table set name = C, value = baz where ID = 9
```

In reality, the list of updates is long. Do I need dynamic SQL to create these separate update queries or is there a better way?

Comment: Need more information in order to answer well, but assuming the database holds the Ids of the records which need to be updated in some other tables, then you want to be doing some sort of Update with Joins.  Depends on what your caller is and where the Ids you want to update & their corresponding new Name and Values come from.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the title, I am guessing that the new data is in a temporary table.  Assuming that each `id` is mentioned only once, you can use `join`:

```
update t
    set name = temp.name,
        values = temp.value
    from t join
         #temp temp
         on t.id = temp.id;
```

You can use `join` even if `id`s appear multiple times.  If so, an indeterminate record in the temporary table will be used for the update.